# Is there a word for irrational anger?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word to describe irrational anger in a similar way that *phobia* is used to describe irrational fear?

Comment: Rage or anti could work.

Comment: Not a single word, but **going ballistic** is a common term. If it involves use of firearms, it could be **going postal**.

Comment: Do you seek a noun or adjective, both?

Comment: In my house it's called "hungry".

Comment: @KennyPeanuts In many a house I'm sure it's also known as _PMS_.

Comment: Yes, it's... *anger*. Perhaps you meant unjustified anger? Anger is an emotion. There might be rational explanations of how emotions work, but emotions are not, themselves, rational. If anything is irrational, anger is.

Comment: All anger is irrational.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for a construction with which to build neologisms, perhaps consider the etymology of misogyny and misandry. In both cases, they are formed from the greek prefix misos-, meaning hatred. [Misos+gyne](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/misogyny) = hatred of women. [Misos+andr](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/misandry) = hatred of men. [Misos+anthropos](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/misanthropy) = hatred of people. In current uses, these are all considered specifically irrational hatreds.

You could conceivably then build *misarachnia* (hatred of spiders) or *misopodia* (hatred of feet?). Being a prefix is awkward though as you'd end up having to add -ia or -alia, the suffixes for "concerning", to make pleasing words. *Mislexicalia* possibly, for the hatred of words, or *misphilatelia*, for the hatred of stamps.

If course, you'll have to contend with the notion that irrational hatreds really are usually rooted in fear. So while mysogyny won over gynophobia, homophobia† is already well established and likely wouldn't yield any room for mishomoalia or even mishominy? Wait, is that the irrational hatred of nixtamalized corn?

† *as an aside, shouldn't that have always been at least homosexophobia? Who's afraid of things that are merely the same? Or rather, if I am afraid of uniformity I feel like I have been robbed of a way of conveying such to other people.*

Comment: This is the closest to what I was looking for. Thank you. If I was going for a single word (rather than a prefix) I think @tushar-raj has convinced me of Temper.

Answer (score 9):

There's **[temper](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/temper)**, or more specifically, **ill-temper**.

> Temper can refer to a tendency to become **unreasonably angry**. If you’re not sure whether you have a temper, ask your friends — but don’t get mad if you dislike what they have to say. <sub>(Vocabulary.com)</sub>

'Temper' is versatile. It can refer to the tendency to become angry, like the definition says; as well as [the state of being angry](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/temper#temper__5).

---

A synonym I like that would be apt here is

[**spleen**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/spleen#spleen__6)

> 2. Bad temper; spite <sub>(Oxford)</sub>

It comes from the old belief that the organ spleen was what caused anger. If your temper causes you to lash out at someone, you're ***venting your spleen.***

Comment: I had no idea that spleen could be used this way. Awesome reference.

Answer (score 8):

A **blind rage** is where someone is acting in an infuriated manner, coupled with a lack of control or self awareness.

> Joe flew into a *blind rage* when he found out his son had broken his favourite saucer that he'd had since childhood. When he'd calmed down he apologised for acting out of character, and took his son to get ice cream.

Comment: Blind refers to *out of control*, not irrational.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps, **fury** or **furious**

> [**fury**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fury) *noun*
>
> **1** **a**. violent anger; rage.
>
> **b**. A fit of anger: "I went into a *fury* and shouted in his face" (William Least Heat-Moon).
>
> **2**. a. violent or frenzied action: the storm's fury.
> b. a violent disturbance or intense period of activity: "The Huns ... moved into Italy, unleashing a *fury* of destruction" (Arther Ferrill).
>
> **3**. in Greek & Roman Mythology, any of the spirits who pursue and torment the doers of unavenged crimes, identified with the Greek *Erinyes*.
>
> [Middle English *furie*, from Old French, from Latin *furia*, from *furere*, to rage.]

(The Free Dictionary)

> [**furor**](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=furor&allowed_in_frame=0) (*n*.) "rage, madness, angry mania," late 15c., from Middle French *fureur* (12c.), from Latin *furor* "a ravaging, rage, ***madness***, passion," which is related to *furia* "rage, passion, fury" (see fury).
>
> [**furious**](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=furious&allowed_in_frame=0) (*adj*.) late 14c., "impetuous, unrestrained," from Old French *furios*, *furieus* "furious, enraged, livid" (14c., Modern French *furieux*), from Latin *furiosus* "full of rage, mad," from *furia* "rage, passion, fury" (see fury). *Furioso*, from the Italian form of the word, was used in English 17c.-18c. for "an enraged person," probably from Ariosto's "Orlando Furioso."
>
> [**infuriate**](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=infuriate&allowed_in_frame=0) (v.) 1660s, from Italian *infuriato*, from Medieval Latin *infuriatus*, past participle of *infuriare* "to madden," from Latin *in furia* "in a fury," from ablative of *furia* (see fury). Related: Infuriated; infuriating; infuriatingly.

(etymonline)

Comment: Hugh did say Fury earlier. So many suggestions. It's hard to notice.

Comment: @Avon - My "fury" includes additional and diverse information.

Comment: It is a better answer for it. I don't know what the etiquette is in such cases. I was thinking of answering with 'wrath' (just because it's an evocative word) but caoimhe has really said it.

Comment: @Avon - the other answer that includes "fury" opens with phobia, -philia, -mania, moves on to road-rage and hate-crime, and ends with "fury". On the other hand, my sole answer is "fury" with linked dictionary definitions, and examples of usage. The etiquette is that one answer should be, in some significant manner, different from the other.

Comment: @Avon - it's difficult to know what the OP is really looking for. I posted a question to OP about this, but it's not likely to be answered, at least in a timely manner (for me).

Comment: I've just realised: when I said "It is a better answer for it." I meant yours and that was, of course, not at all clear.

Answer (score 2):

**-phobia, -philia, -mania,** seem to be out on their own for compound words

road-**rage**   and

**hate**-crime  ::seem like improvisations to fill the gap.

But **fury** is nearly out of control:

> On 28 March 2013, Lewandowsky published "Recursive fury: Conspiracist
>   ideation in the blogosphere in response to research on conspiracist
>   ideation"    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephan_Lewandowsky

Answer (score 2):

**wrath** is extreme anger. Not necessarily out of control but can be.

If the anger is vengeful then I would recommend it as appropriate. It has an almost onomatopoeic timbre.

Example definition:

> noun
>  : extreme anger
>
> Full Definition of WRATH
>  1:  strong vengeful anger or
>   indignation
>  2:  retributory punishment for an offense or a crime :
>   divine chastisement

([merriam-webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wrath))

Comment: We're in the basement, brother. :- (

Comment: @LittleEva I hear that's where the Tenacious badge can be found.

Comment: "*Now that my ladder's gone,
 I must lie down where all ladders start,
 In the foul, rag and bone shop of the heart." ---Robert Bly

Answer (score 2):

**hissy fit** (*noun*):

- an angry outburst; temper tantrum  [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com)

> *'I screamed and kicked the furniture and threw a hissy fit.'*

- a sudden period of uncontrolled and silly anger, like a child's [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org)
- an outburst or display of excited anger [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com)

> *'The demanding diva had a major hissy fit when she had to wait for her trailer to be ready.'*

**strop** (*noun, British informal*):

- a bad mood; a temper  [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com)

> *'Nathalie gets in a strop and makes to leave.'*

- a bad mood, especially one in which a person will not do what they are asked and is unpleasant to other people  [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org)

> *'Don't go in unless you have to; he's in a real strop.'*

Answer (score 1):

[Hysteria](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hysteria),  or  *hysterical attacks* may be examples of irrational, uncontrollable outburst of rage:

> - ***an uncontrollable emotional outburst***, as from fear or grief, ***often characterized by irrationality***, laughter, weeping, etc.
> - behaviour exhibiting excessive or uncontrollable emotion, such as fear or panic.

The Free Dictionary

Comment: "Given the traditional understanding of anger as a male emotion and hysteria as associated with women, it may come as a surprise to us that this hysterical patient is a man, one feminised by his hysteria as a result of repressing his rage." Statistical Panic, Kathleen Woodward 2009

Comment: In fairness, I wouldn't associate hysteria with anger. Could you give an example sentence demonstrating this usage?

Comment: I agree with @dwjohnston. I would associate hysteria with fear, not anger. The Hulk is anything but hysterical.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - what makes you think that anger may not be the result of fear?

Comment: It can be. But so can sweat, and you wouldn’t say that _hysteria_ means ‘sweat’, either. Fear and anger are related notions, but words for one do not necessarily mean the other. All the examples you quote are related to fear and do not mention anger at all; and even if anger is present in a hysterical attack, it is not the sole or main aspect. Since the question is asking specifically for a word that relates to anger _as opposed to_ fear, giving a word that relates mainly to fear and only secondarily (sometimes) to anger seems inadequate.

Comment: Please read my answer : "hysterical attacks may be examples of irrational, uncontrolled outbursts of rage".

Comment: This can be a somewhat difficult question to answer as the OP has not expressed whether they seek a noun, adjective, or both. There is, of course "hysterical anger" and "hysterical laughter."

Answer (score 1):

Consider "[delirium](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/delirium)".

> 1. usually brief state of excitement and mental confusion often accompanied by hallucinations
>
> 2.state of **violent mental agitation**
>
> 3.a frenzy of emotion; as for something unattainable
>
> Synonyms:craze, **frenzy**, fury, **hysteria** 
>   Type      :*nympholepsy*

And if you’ve ever stayed up all night writing a paper or working hard to meet some deadline, you’ve probably experienced moments of delirium, where you feel crazed and hallucinatory, fueled by sleep deprivation and too much coffee.

(vocabulary.com)

Comment: _delirium_ is more about the internal state of mind, rather than external behaviour. Somebody could probably be quietly delirious, without anyone noticing anything, whereas _anger_ is usually a more engaging state.  Origin: *delirare* — _to leave a straight line, be mad_, from *lira* — _line cut in the ground_. I assume that _be mad_ here signifies a mental disorder rather than intense anger.